# jpql error near where

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpql

Hi I am learning `JPQL` and I am selecting `DTO` with following code

```
class User{
private int id;
private String name;

@oneToOne
private Service service;

}
Class Service{
private int id
private String serviceName;
}

class UserServiceDTO{

private String userName;
private String serviceName;

public UserServiceDTO(String userName,String serviceName){
this.userName=userName;
this.serviceName-serviceName;
}
}

public UserServiceDTO findByName(String userName){
TypedQuery<UserServiceDTO> query= em.createQuery("SELECT new UserServiceDTO(u.name, s.userName) FROM User u LEFT OUTER JOIN Service s where 
 u.name LIKE :userName");
 UserServiceDTO userService=query.setParameter("userName",userName).getSingleReslut();
}
```

I am getting following stacktrace:

```
Could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"
  Position: 260
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:420)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 43 more
```

I am using `PostgreSQL`
Any Insight will be helpfull. Please help me where I am wrong possible please guide me

Comment: `User u LEFT OUTER JOIN Service s `is also no valid jpql join

Comment: you don't define join column

Comment: @NicoVanBelle can you please provide little more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax for that JPQL would be

```
SELECT new UserServiceDTO(u.name, s.serviceName) FROM User u LEFT OUTER JOIN u.service s WHERE u.name LIKE :userName
```

The joins are done through the entity graph, so you just specify the entity fields you want to access.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, Now, I am getting below error as
`could not resolve property: Service of: User`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to explicitly join.You can also write: SELECT new UserServiceDTO(u.name, u.service.serviceName) FROM User u where u.name LIKE :userName; You may need to specify join column mapping usimg @JoinColumn annotation